# Difficulty with interpreting correctly the statement of a proposition involving "for every": which version is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here it is the proposition which I am concerned with:

Let $X$ be a subset of $\textbf{R}$, let $f:X\to\textbf{R}$ be a function, let $E$ be a subset of $X$, let $x_{0}$ be an adherent point of $E$, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following two statements are logically equivalent

(a) $f$ converges to $L$ at $x_{0}$ in $E$.

(b) For every sequence $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ which consists of elements of $E$ and converges to $x_{0}$, the sequence $(f(a_{n}))_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to L

> My question is: is it enough to check condition (b) for just one sequence or do we have to prove that such condition holds for every sequence satisfying the corresponding restrictions?

Maybe my difficulty of interpreting correctly the sentence is due to the fact that I am not a native English speaker. So I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

Comment: "For every sequence" means you have to show it holds for every sequence satisfying the conditions. It's not enough to just check it for one sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It has helped a lot.

Comment: By the way checking for each and every sequence is handled by precisely dealing with _just one arbitrary_ sequence. The idea is that you can not take any specific sequence of your choice like say $x_0-1/n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to proving that the statements (a) and (b) are equivalent.

First, you start by assuming (a), and then prove that (b) holds. That is, you suppose that it is true that the function $f$ has the limit $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$, and then you show that *for every* sequence $(a_n)$ in $E$ that converges to $x_0$, the sequence $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$. It does not suffice to show that there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ for which $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$. You need to show this for *every* such sequence.

Secondly, you start by assuming (b), and then prove that (a) holds. That is, you suppose that for *every sequence* $(a_n)$ in $E$ that converges to $x_0$, the sequence $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$, and you show that $f$ has the limit $L$ at $x_0$ in $E$. It does not suffice to assume that there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ for which $f(a_n)$ converges to $L$. You need to assume that this happens for *every* such sequence.

Comment: Many thanks for the contribution @Brahadeesh. Your comments are valuable!